# How to change hibernate's default fetching strategy?

Tags: hibernate, fetching-strategy

I know hibernate's default fetching strategy is LAZY for collections, is there a way to change the default fetching strategy system wide through configuration file?

Comment: There isn't. The best you can do is 'default-lazy' attribute on `<hibernate-mapping>`: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-mapping

Comment: Dead link above. See https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2372843

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any good answer for your need, sorry. :-(

---

But may I dare challenging your requirement? ;-)

1. If you enable early fetching for collections (ie. XToMany, or parent to child relationship), it is probable that it is also adequate to **enable the other side** (XToOne), that is much more likely needed.
2. Considering that often, your entities are not fully partitionned, that is "there is a chain of entities allowing to go **from any entity to any other entity**"...
3. We deduce that **even your simplest request will load the entire database** !

This is the reason why I think it is "*unlikely a good idea*".

Comment: +1. Setting **all** associations to be eagerly fetched is **never** a good idea.

Comment: I was trying to set global fetching strategy to lazy